# Превью статьи (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Вопрос от новичка, как сделать превью статьи с кнопкой "Read more", используя PHP? Знаю, что функцией substr, но не могу понять что к чему.

Comment: обычно документу (новость/статья и т.п.) добавляют пару полей - краткий текст (анонс), и полный текст, и тогда резать ничего не надо.

Comment: К сожалению, таково задание.)

Comment: ну вот поищите тогда, на этой неделе была такая задача.

Comment: Дополнительное поле анонса это самый простой вариант. Еще два варианта: обрезать текст по длине и/или по специальной строке типа <hr class='cut'> которую вы сами размещаете в тексте где хотите. Но при обрезании надо не сломать верстку, если контент поста в html.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и обычный вариант:

```
function truncateText($text, $length) {
    return strlen($text) > $length ? substr($text,0,$length)."..." : $text;
}

echo truncateText("Текст текст текст");
```